# Pandas interpolate() backwards in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Going forward, [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate) works great:

```
       name    days
0      a       NaN
1      a       NaN
2      a         2
3      a         3
4      a       NaN 
5      a       NaN  

records.loc[:, 'days'].interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)

       name    days
0      a       NaN
1      a       NaN
2      a         2
3      a         3
4      a         4 
5      a         5
```

...however, it does not address the beginning rows (only goes forward). The `limit_direction` param allows `{‘forward’, ‘backward’, ‘both’}`. None of these works. Is there a proper way to interpolate backwards?

We can assume a series incrementing or decrementing by 1, which may not start at 0 as it happens to in this example.

Comment: Your example *(6 rows shown)* as such will not work(values would remain same as the last known value), as `interpolate` needs to know the first valid value after `Nan` to extrapolate those values based on gauging it's difference between the rows whose values are to be filled. So, linear interpolation works best when you specify it's starting and ending points, so that it can nicely smooth the `NaN` values it encounters mid-way.

Comment: The current version of pandas (0.22) seems to do the trick with `limit_direction='both'`. Starting and ending `NaN` values are now **padded** though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems it works only with parameter `limit` see [docs [In 47]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-enhancements-other):

> Add a **limit_direction** keyword argument that works with **limit** to enable interpolate to fill NaN values forward, backward, or both (GH9218, GH10420, GH11115)

```
records = pd.DataFrame(
{'name': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'a', 5: 'a', 6: 'a', 7: 'a', 8: 'a', 9: 'a'}, 
'days': {0: 0.0, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 4.0, 5: 5.0, 6: np.nan, 7: np.nan, 8: np.nan, 9: 9.0}}, 
columns=['name','days'])

print (records)
  name  days
0    a   0.0
1    a   NaN
2    a   NaN
3    a   NaN
4    a   4.0
5    a   5.0
6    a   NaN
7    a   NaN
8    a   NaN
9    a   9.0
```

```
#by default limit_direction='forward'
records['forw'] = records['days'].interpolate(method='linear', 
                                              limit=1)
records['backw'] = records['days'].interpolate(method='linear',
                                               limit_direction='backward', 
                                               limit=1)
records['both'] = records['days'].interpolate(method='linear', 
                                              limit_direction='both', 
                                              limit=1)
print (records)
  name  days  forw  backw  both
0    a   0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0
1    a   NaN   1.0    NaN   1.0
2    a   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
3    a   NaN   NaN    3.0   3.0
4    a   4.0   4.0    4.0   4.0
5    a   5.0   5.0    5.0   5.0
6    a   NaN   6.0    NaN   6.0
7    a   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
8    a   NaN   NaN    8.0   8.0
9    a   9.0   9.0    9.0   9.0
```

Comment: Can you get the entire column populated with the linear sequence?

Comment: Do you think assign output to column?

Comment: Using the example I provided, the first two records had missing values. This creates a problem

Comment: I think it can works only with `limit` parameter , see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/10691#issuecomment-136174558)

Comment: and `limit_direction='backward'`