# Filling in past and future data from partial data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have take a cumulative sum for data that goes up from 198x to 2016 and is now in the form:

```
State   Year    Month   Value
TN      1987    1       24410.0
TN      1987    2       24410.0
TN      1987    3       24410.0
TN      1987    4       24410.0
.
.
TN      1996    1       24410.0
TN      1996    2       24410.0
TN      1996    3       24410.0
TN      1996    4       24410.0
TN      1996    5       37109.0
TN      1996    6       37109.0
TN      1996    7       37109.0
TN      1996    8       37109.0
TN      1996    9       37109.0
TN      1996    10      37109.0
TN      1996    11      37109.0
TN      1996    12      37109.0
TN      2016    1       49808.0
TN      2016    2       49808.0
```

The data actually skips from 1996 to 2016 (for the case of TN but varies on State to State). I need to find a method to generally fill all the missing holes in the data because some years just don't exist (2010-2015) and I want to fill them so that the output goes all the way to 2018.

I want the missing values to be filled with values preceding from the values before to get an **output** that looks like:

```
TN      1996    4       24410.0
TN      1996    5       37109.0
TN      1996    6       37109.0
.
.
TN      2010    1       37109.0
TN      2010    2       37109.0
TN      2010    3       37109.0
.
.
TN      2016    1       37109.0
TN      2016    2       37109.0
.
.
TN      2016    11      49808.0
TN      2016    12      49808.0
.
.
TN      2017    1       49808.0
TN      2017    2       49808.0
TN      2017    3       49808.0
TN      2017    4       49808.0
.
.
TN      2018    1       49808.0
TN      2018    2       49808.0
```

Comment: Have you tried any methods yet? Look at `fillna()` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna)

Comment: @HelloToEarth could you check the accepted answer so the post can be closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe with the missing months and them merge your result with it:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/%d' %df['Year'].min(),
                      end='1/08/%d' %df['Year'].max(),
                      freq='MS', closed='left')

>> dates

DatetimeIndex(['1987-02-01', '1987-03-01', '1987-04-01', '1987-05-01',
               '1987-06-01', '1987-07-01', '1987-08-01', '1987-09-01',
               '1987-10-01', '1987-11-01',
               ...
               '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01',
               '2015-08-01', '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01',
               '2015-12-01', '2016-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=348, freq='MS')
```

Then you can create a dataframe with all the months:

```
all_months = pd.DataFrame.from_records((dates.year, dates.month),
      index=['Year', 'Month']).T.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Month'])
```

And then merge it with the original dataframe and forward-fill it:

```
df.merge(all_months, how='right').ffill()

    State    Year  Month    Value
0      TN  1987.0    1.0  24410.0
1      TN  1987.0    2.0  24410.0
2      TN  1987.0    3.0  24410.0
3      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
4      TN  1996.0    1.0  24410.0
5      TN  1996.0    2.0  24410.0
6      TN  1996.0    3.0  24410.0
7      TN  1996.0    4.0  24410.0
8      TN  1996.0    5.0  37109.0
9      TN  1996.0    6.0  37109.0
10     TN  1996.0    7.0  37109.0
11     TN  1996.0    8.0  37109.0
12     TN  1996.0    9.0  37109.0
13     TN  1996.0   10.0  37109.0
14     TN  1996.0   11.0  37109.0
15     TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0
16     TN  2016.0    1.0  49808.0
17     TN  1987.0    5.0  49808.0
18     TN  1987.0    6.0  49808.0
19     TN  1987.0    7.0  49808.0
20     TN  1987.0    8.0  49808.0
21     TN  1987.0    9.0  49808.0
22     TN  1987.0   10.0  49808.0
23     TN  1987.0   11.0  49808.0
24     TN  1987.0   12.0  49808.0
25     TN  1988.0    1.0  49808.0
26     TN  1988.0    2.0  49808.0
27     TN  1988.0    3.0  49808.0
28     TN  1988.0    4.0  49808.0
29     TN  1988.0    5.0  49808.0
..    ...     ...    ...      ...
319    TN  2013.0    7.0  49808.0
320    TN  2013.0    8.0  49808.0
321    TN  2013.0    9.0  49808.0
322    TN  2013.0   10.0  49808.0
323    TN  2013.0   11.0  49808.0
324    TN  2013.0   12.0  49808.0
325    TN  2014.0    1.0  49808.0
326    TN  2014.0    2.0  49808.0
327    TN  2014.0    3.0  49808.0
328    TN  2014.0    4.0  49808.0
329    TN  2014.0    5.0  49808.0
330    TN  2014.0    6.0  49808.0
331    TN  2014.0    7.0  49808.0
332    TN  2014.0    8.0  49808.0
333    TN  2014.0    9.0  49808.0
334    TN  2014.0   10.0  49808.0
335    TN  2014.0   11.0  49808.0
336    TN  2014.0   12.0  49808.0
337    TN  2015.0    1.0  49808.0
338    TN  2015.0    2.0  49808.0
339    TN  2015.0    3.0  49808.0
340    TN  2015.0    4.0  49808.0
341    TN  2015.0    5.0  49808.0
342    TN  2015.0    6.0  49808.0
343    TN  2015.0    7.0  49808.0
344    TN  2015.0    8.0  49808.0
345    TN  2015.0    9.0  49808.0
346    TN  2015.0   10.0  49808.0
347    TN  2015.0   11.0  49808.0
348    TN  2015.0   12.0  49808.0
```

**Using [pandas.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)**

Another solution is index by date and then resample there:

```
df['Day'] = 1

df1 = df.assign(date= lambda x:pd.to_datetime(x[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])).set_index('date')

>> df1

           State    Year  Month    Value  Day
date                                         
1987-01-01    TN  1987.0    1.0  24410.0    1
1987-02-01    TN  1987.0    2.0  24410.0    1
1987-03-01    TN  1987.0    3.0  24410.0    1
1987-04-01    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0    1
1996-01-01    TN  1996.0    1.0  24410.0    1
1996-02-01    TN  1996.0    2.0  24410.0    1
1996-03-01    TN  1996.0    3.0  24410.0    1
1996-04-01    TN  1996.0    4.0  24410.0    1
1996-05-01    TN  1996.0    5.0  37109.0    1
1996-06-01    TN  1996.0    6.0  37109.0    1
1996-07-01    TN  1996.0    7.0  37109.0    1
1996-08-01    TN  1996.0    8.0  37109.0    1
1996-09-01    TN  1996.0    9.0  37109.0    1
1996-10-01    TN  1996.0   10.0  37109.0    1
1996-11-01    TN  1996.0   11.0  37109.0    1
1996-12-01    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0    1
2016-01-01    TN  2016.0    1.0  49808.0    1
2016-02-01    TN  2016.0    2.0  49808.0    1
```

Then you can resample it by month by doing:

```
    res = df1.resample('M').first().ffill()

    >> res 

               State    Year  Month    Value  Day
    date                                         
    1987-01-31    TN  1987.0    1.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-02-28    TN  1987.0    2.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-03-31    TN  1987.0    3.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-04-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-05-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-06-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-07-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-08-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-09-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-10-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-11-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1987-12-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-01-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-02-29    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-03-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-04-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-05-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-06-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-07-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-08-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-09-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-10-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-11-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1988-12-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1989-01-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1989-02-28    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1989-03-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1989-04-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1989-05-31    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    1989-06-30    TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0  1.0
    ...          ...     ...    ...      ...  ...
    2013-09-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2013-10-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2013-11-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2013-12-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-01-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-02-28    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-03-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-04-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-05-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-06-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-07-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-08-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-09-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-10-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-11-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2014-12-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-01-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-02-28    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-03-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-04-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-05-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-06-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-07-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-08-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-09-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-10-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-11-30    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2015-12-31    TN  1996.0   12.0  37109.0  1.0
    2016-01-31    TN  2016.0    1.0  49808.0  1.0
    2016-02-29    TN  2016.0    2.0  49808.0  1.0
```

You can get the original structure by doing:

```
>> res.reset_index(drop=True).drop(['Day'], axis=1).head()

        State    Year  Month    Value
    0      TN  1987.0    1.0  24410.0
    1      TN  1987.0    2.0  24410.0
    2      TN  1987.0    3.0  24410.0
    3      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
    4      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
    5      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
    6      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
    7      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
    8      TN  1987.0    4.0  24410.0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `pandas.interpolate`?: interpolate values according to different methods

See section 'interpolate' here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

And some existing example previously posted: [Pandas interpolate() backwards in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582640/pandas-interpolate-backwards-in-dataframe)